# Enter-PSSession with existing session

Tags: powershell

I created a session with `$remote = New-PsSesion ...` and I want to use it later interactively.

I tried `Enter-PSSesion -Session $remote` but it complains *Enter-PSSession : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters*. The same happens when using `Id` parameter.

=== EDIT ===

```
> New-PSSession

 Id Name            ComputerName    ComputerType    State         ConfigurationName     Availability
 -- ----            ------------    ------------    -----         -----------------     ------------
  1 Session1        localhost       RemoteMachine   Opened        Microsoft.PowerShell     Available



> etsn -Id 1
Enter-PSSession : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ etsn -Id 1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Enter-PSSession], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.EnterPSSessionCommand


> $host


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 5.1.14393.1198
InstanceId       : ab8e55cd-69ae-4587-a70a-c66f197028a4
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : sr-Latn-RS
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

Comment: Are you using any other parameters? I just tested it in my test environment and it all worked correctly. Output from my environment in below comment. Also, just re-read your question, looks like you are missing an S in New-PSSession. You have New-PSSesion.

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $dc1remote = New-PSSession -VMName dc1 -Credential timhaintz\administrator

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enter-PSSession $dc1remote

[dc1]: PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> exit

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enter-PSSession -Session $dc1remote

[dc1]: PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> exit

Comment: What is your PS Version and can you show what you full session definition looks like... scrubbed if you prefer.

Comment: Added output above

Comment: What parameters are you using with New-PSSession? AmbiguousParamaterSet usually means you have settings from multiple Paramater Sets.

Comment: As you can see above, no parameters

Comment: If I type New-PSSession with no parameters it just hangs.

Comment: Are you using a powershell profile that messes with the Enter-PSSession Cmdlet? I have seen people wrapping Cmdlets into functions of the same name to provide their own default values for parameters. Can you verify that the 'etsn' alias points to the Enter-PSSession Cmdlet?

Comment: @ManuelBatsching, you are right, thats it. I am using the proxy function which only translated DNS alias to computer name. Its failure is probably that there is no default parameter set.

Comment: @majkinetor That is because '-ComputerName' and '-Session' belong to separate parameter sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments to your question, the reason you get this exception is that you wrapped your custom function around the `Enter-PSSession` cmdlet. Your custom function apparently always specifies the `-ComputerName` parameter, even if you are not using it.

As `-Session` is a parameter from a different parameter set than `-ComputerName` you will not be able to use it unless you modify your wrapper around `Enter-PSSession` accordingly.

Comment: If you have more than one device on your network that uses the same IP address, being unable to connect to a PowerShell session is the least of your problems.